# react-native-fbsdk working n ios side but not working on android side I have fully setup the facebook app

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

> Facebook login error app, not setup: the app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. switch to registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1:**

In Settings -> Basic -> Contact Email. (Give your/any email)

**STEP 2:** In 'App Review' Tab : change

Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? **Yes**